# The model name you are loading is the name of a resource that is already being used: base_model

Tags: php, codeigniter, model

When I load my base_model normally, it's ok. But when I use autoload.php to load base_model, I get a problem:

> The model name you are loading is the name of a resource that is
>   already being used: base_model

Please help me solve this!:)

Answer (score 1):

Once you `autoload` the model in `autoload.php`, again you try to load the same file some or the another controller or model, this will show following error.

```
The model name you are loading is the name of a resource that is already being used: base_model
```

to avoid that i will just recommend that do not load that model anywhere in the full application once you `autoload` that particular model.

Comment: But when I create a new model with a new name(ex:abc_model) and autoload it, I still get this problem. Why it happen? I didn't load or use it anywhere.

Comment: its better you to check codeigniter user guide.
Couple of issues i knows as follows
1. while autoloading the file, just type filename without php extension.
2. while creating model file, follow the naming convention. like file name must be in small case like `abc_model` and then while defining the class it must be `Abc_Model extends CI_Model` etc.

Comment: I did exactly what you said but it didn't work! But thank you so much for your help:)! Can you show me another way:D, bro!

Comment: I did it! I found that I need to change index function in my default controller to __construct.
Thanks so much!:D

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness I want to refer to this [blog post](https://blog.crusy.net/codeigniter-the-model-name-you-are-loading-is-the-name-of-a-resource-that-is-already-being-used/) (in german) that suggests loading the models without a name.

```
1 // yes :-)
2 $this->load->model('stream_model');
3 $this->stream_model->foo();
```

instead of

```
1 // NO!
2 $this->load->model('stream_model', 'stream');
3 $this->stream->foo();
```

It helped me because I didn't have an auto loader configured and the model wansn't loaded inside the controller (or its super classes).

Answer (score -1):

I know this is old post...
If you put `parent::__construct` in any controller function (except constructor) you get this message.

Comment: You should edit this to make it more clear, add details and use proper formatting.