# Codeigniter - Autoload Model Always Failing

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks, autoloader

I have recently picked up the framework Codeigniter, but I seem to be stuck with a problem.

Whenever I use the model autoloader it gaves me the same error:
- "The model name you are loading is the name of a resource that is already being used: "

In case you need my code to solve the problem. In my code I am using JQuery/Ajax. It makes a call to controller "Encounter".

The reasonable thing to check is if I'm calling the automatically loaded model anywhere, but I'm not as far as I checked.

I have changed the code a bit to leave out unimportant parts.

```
class Encounter extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /* *
     * Summary: Load descriptive, mutative (statistical) data
     * @params: N/A
     * #return: N/A
     */
    public function startEncounter()
    {
        $encounter_id = $_POST['encounter_id'];

        switch ($encounter_id)
        {
            case 1:
                $this->load->model('target_model', 'target');
                break;
        }

        $this->target->Start();
    }
}
```

Here is the target_model:

```
class Target_model extends CI_Model {

    //  Has the player met the target before
    public $F_hasMet = false;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function Start()
    {
        $this->SayHello();
        $this->encounter_model->CallDialog();
    }

    /* *
     * Summary: Say hello
     * @params: N/A
     * #return: N/A
     */
    public function SayHello()
    {
        $this->encounter_model->SetDialog("Hello");
        $this->F_hasMet = true;
    }

}
```

My autoload:

```
$autoload['model'] = array('encounter_model');
```

Class I'm trying to autoload:

```
class Encounter_model extends CI_Model {

/* *
 * Summary: Interactive data
 */
public $dialog = '';

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    if ( ! $this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        $this->output->set_status_header('401');
    }
}

/* *
 * Summary: Add or replace dialog
 * @params: Message, addition
 * #return: N/A
 */
public function SetDialog($message, $addition = true)
{
    if ($addition) {
        $this->dialog .= $message;
    } else {
        $this->dialog = $message;
    }
}

/* *
 * Summary: Displays the current dialog to the screen
 * @params: Message, addition
 * #return: N/A
 */
public function CallDialog()
{       
    $this->output
       ->set_content_type('application/json')
       ->set_header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK")
       ->set_output(json_encode($this->dialog));
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem that you are trying to reload this model somewhere in the code. Try to search this and remove the possible duplication.

for further help see this.

[The model name you are loading is the name of a resource that is already being used: base_model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029638/the-model-name-you-are-loading-is-the-name-of-a-resource-that-is-already-being-u)

Comment: Thank you for your time, but thia should not be the case. Even if I create an entirely new model it throws the same error.

Comment: I don't see how this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I will mark this as answer because the link provided pushed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had the following code:

```
class Index extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->view('game');
    }
}
```

But I have to put the construct inside the constructor..

```
class Index extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('game');
    }
}
```